# How can i make HTML p having text box properties?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to give html *input* text box properties to html *p* element.

If you type anything in text box and text exceeds width of text box, it automatically slides down in left direction making left most character hidden and new character appended at the end. This is text box default behavior.

I want to achieve same thing with HTML *p*,

I have a situation where *p* is used to hold text. I mean whichever key you type that character will be displayed in *p* and each character will be appended at the end. As number of character increases more then the *p*'s width, appended character at the end (right most) becomes invisible. That is characters are not shifting in left direction as they do in text box.

Showing scroll in *p* is not an option (as in text box also you don't see scroll) so that is ruled out.

Can anyone give me any input to achieve this? I am not using any library.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Use <textarea name="myname" rows="10" cols="10"></textarea>

Comment: It'll be way easier to just use an input and dress it up in your p-tag styling than the other way around. You'll need to play around with css overflow settings and the positioning of the text inside to achieve the same result on a p-tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `contenteditable` attribute, mixin some CSS properties like `white-space` and `overflow`:

```css
p {
  white-space:nowrap;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  }
```

```html
<p contenteditable="true">Edit this &lt;p&gt; element with a long text</p>
```

### EDITED

Due the comments section, OP needs to hide the scrollbar, so the final code should be:

```css
p {
  white-space:nowrap;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<p contenteditable="true">Edit this &lt;p&gt; element with a long text</p>
```

Comment: using overflow: auto showing an scroll bar in p so i can not use it.

Comment: You need an overflow invisible but controlable? You need to set `overflow: hidden`